# Global variables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I wanted to create a sql script and do something like this:

```
DECLARE @SomeVariable int
SET @SomeVariable = 'VALUE'
  FROM someTable
--do stuff with @SomeVariable
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
(
  @MyParameter
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

--Do something
--Do something using @SomeVariable
SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN 0
GO
```

I can't, because @SomeVariable dies with the batch he belongs to, and myProcedure requires its own batch.  Obviously I could create a #temp table and stuff any values I needed in there, but then I would have to select from it - adding code that, while trivial, hurts readability and seems silly when all I need is a global variable.  Is there a better way?

To be painfully clear.  I KNOW SQL Server has "global variables" called "tables" - I mentioned in the above paragraph that using a #table is a possible solution, as is using an actual permanent table.  What I'm looking for here is probably more of a global constant that I can use anywhere within a given script, not a global variable - so we can all stop wetting our pants about the evils of global variables.

Comment: Oh boy, what is the world coming to. :(

Comment: What are you doing that requires a global variable?  If we knew more, we could provide alternatives.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for a global variable or a global constant?

Comment: SQL Server does have global variables - they are called tables.

Comment: This is *exactly* what Temporary tables were created for.  Get over it and use them.  Stop trying to write C in SQL.

Comment: Alright, I'll accept a downvote or two for being snide, but does nobody see the improved readability and writability that might come from being able to reference a constant rather than selecting the value from a table or temporary table every time you want to use it?

Comment: @Zannjaminderson You can use a scalar udf for that - see the bottom of Case 3 in my answer.

Comment: You can use CONTEXT_INFO to persist information on the connection, but I'm not sure what your batches are for.

Comment: @Cade Roux:  I have a lot of respect for you, Cade, but I think that CONTEXT_INFO is a *very* bad thing.

Comment: @angryboy I agree CONTEXT_INFO is a bad thing, but if you need to persist something on the connection between calls it's a way to do it.  Personally, I typically use one connection per call, so I don't have occasion to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't clear why the stored proc has a dependency on your global in your example set of two batches.  I see two main possibilities: either the SP has a dependency on the global at time of creation (i.e. code generation - Case 1), or the SP has a runtime dependency on the global (i.e. you must choose between parameterization - Case 2 - or self-configuration - Case3).

In the case of runtime dependency, whether that is obtained from some place outside the SP and passed in as a parameter or inside the SP directly is the basic design decision.  The choice of when to pass data as a parameter and when to pull from tables is not exactly a science, it all depends on all the real-world usage cases in the system.

Case 1 - Code generation:

```
DECLARE @SomeVariable int 
SET @SomeVariable = 'VALUE' 
  FROM someTable 
--do stuff with @SomeVariable 
GO 

DECLARE @sp as varchar(MAX)

SET @sp = '
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure -- I would actually name this myProcedure_ + CONVERT(varchar, @SomeVariable), since each proc generated might function differently
( 
  @MyParameter 
) 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @SomeVariable AS int -- This is going to be an initialized local copy of the global at time of SP creation
SET @SomeVariable = ' + CONVERT(varchar, @SomeVariable) + '

--Do something 
--Do something using @SomeVariable 
SET NOCOUNT OFF 
RETURN 0 
'
EXEC(@sp) -- create the procedure dynamically

Executing the producedure normally as EXEC myProcedure or EXEC myProcedure_1, etc.
```

Case 2 - Parametrization:

```
DECLARE @SomeVariable int 
SET @SomeVariable = 'VALUE' 
  FROM someTable 
--do stuff with @SomeVariable 
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure 
( 
  @MyParameter 
  ,@SomeVariable int
) 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

--Do something 
--Do something using @SomeVariable 
SET NOCOUNT OFF 
RETURN 0 
GO
```

Now whenever `myProcedure` is called, it must always be passed the parameter `@SomeVariable`.  This is recommended when you are calling the same SP with different parametrization regularly

Case 3 - Configuration:

```
DECLARE @SomeVariable int 
SET @SomeVariable = 'VALUE' 
  FROM someTable 
--do stuff with @SomeVariable 
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure 
( 
  @MyParameter 
) 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

--Do something 
DECLARE @SomeVariable int 
SET @SomeVariable = 'VALUE' 
  FROM someTable 

SET NOCOUNT OFF 
RETURN 0 
GO
```

Now, whenever you EXEC myProcedure, you need to ensure that the configuration has been set in the table.  This scenario is recommended for slowly-changing configuration cases.  In this case, you can wrap the `@SomeVariable` initialization in a scalar-valued UDF, so that any times this same configuration is used in different SPs, they will all call through the same UDF, which frees you to change your configuration table conventions (you don't give your users SELECT permission on your tables, anyway, right?) and if the UDF needs to start varying based on user or similar, you now have a control point which enforces consistency, permissions and interface calling conventions:

```
DECLARE @SomeVariable int 
SET @SomeVariable = dbo.udf_Global(username, session, etc.)
--do stuff with @SomeVariable 
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure 
( 
  @MyParameter 
) 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

--Do something 
DECLARE @SomeVariable int 
SET @SomeVariable = dbo.udf_Global(username, session, etc.)

SET NOCOUNT OFF 
RETURN 0 
GO
```

Comment: I think the table solution is probably the way I would still go in this case, but the dynamic declaration of the stored procedure is a slick idea and I appreciate your extremely thorough analysis of my question.  I'm accepting this answer because of how well thought-out and explained it is.

Comment: I don't think we really understood enough about your system as to why you were doing these completely different types of batches in order.  Typically, the stored procedures are a long-term part of the database, and would not be changed on an extremely frequent basis.

Answer (score 6):

The GO statement, which is not part of the SQL language specification, is a batch separator. Your local variables are scoped to the batch. Therefore, they go out of scope at the GO statement. I think your only alternative is something along the lines of what you described.

Comment: Oh... I thought "GO" was just a polite request for aggregated scripts to continue running normally. +1

Comment: Yeah, the crux of this problem is just that - how can we preserve some value where we can use it across batches without just stuffing it in a table.  I figured I'd see if there was any other way, but alas it appears there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after some globally persistent value that multiple different procedures can use then storing it in a table is the best I can think of.

If you just want a variable that you use within a single procedure multiple times then you include it within the procedure definition.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure 
( 
  @MyParameter 
) 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @SomeVariable int 
SET @SomeVariable = 'VALUE' 
  FROM someTable 
--do stuff with @SomeVariable 

--Do something 
--Do something using @SomeVariable 
SET NOCOUNT OFF 
RETURN 0 
GO
```

And if you want some nice encapsulation of logic that you can reference in a convenient way, then a scalar User Defined Function (UDF) could be what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that we need a bit more context on this, as I don't really see the point here, but I can give you a bit of insight based on what I do know.

You have two different batches here, one that is just a regular block of code, and the other that, does NOT actually do anything but creates a stored procedure.

If you need the stored procedure to have a value to work with, just make it an input.

If you need to share the above value across stored procedures, potentially you could use a scalar function to return the value that you need on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Global variable is bad practice in any programming language.  Why not just pass the variable as a parameter in the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
(
  @MyParameter,
  @SomeVariable  -- the global variable
)
AS
...
```

Comment: Not true. Globals, and their OO friends "statics," have plenty of valid uses.  You just need to code defensively.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a table called something like `dbo.Configuration`, which you can store a bunch of values in, pulling them out when you need? It'll be one or two pages at most, so quick to access, probably left in RAM the whole time, and you can dip into it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old topic, the question is still valid.  The "why" isn't the question (i.e. Gates saying "[why] would anyone need more that 64k?" :) )  but I'll provide and example:

Assuming a client using SQL 2012 (so the happy session context isn't available beyond the limited single binary(128) value vs named variables):

1. The client isn't interested in supporting RLS
2. The client is leveraging a multi-tenant approach
3. The view is for tenant 1 is joining across tables and part of the join is the list of tenant values that restrict the set (obviously this would be a different value depending on the tenant accessing the view)
4. The tenant is using a linked server in this join

Putting in a join to another table is death across a casual linked server.  "passing" the restriction values to the linked-server side reduces the resultset returned.  A function is going to do the same thing.  Obviously, for 2016 forward this could be accomplished with a session context, but again - the limitation on 2012 won't suffice.

What would be "nice" (and readable in a view) would be something such as
select *
from server1 a
inner join (select * from abc.db.dbo.tbl where somevalue in (@@RestrictedList)) b
on a.field = b.field

just thinking... :)

If this were a proc - okilies.  no problem.  but... since they are views, well poop lol.

to answer, IF you aren't using a linked server and on 2012 and prior, an approach would be a UDF (careful... evaluate performance depending on how you use it).
If you use something > 2012 and not across a linked server then session context would work (then you have to set it on that context)