# SQL Server PROCEDURE Variable Declaration

Tags: sql, variables, stored-procedures, declaration, procedure

I got a doubt why we have to reassign the variable to new value when we are calling a stored procedure with parameter.
In procedure we need 2 variables. and that variables need to be reassigned for using inside the procedure.

Comment: Show your code, illustrate your problem, read [ask]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter sniffing

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/

> SQL Server compiles the stored procedures using (sniffing) the
>   parameters send the first time the procedure is compiled and put it in
>   plan cache. After that every time the procedure executed again, SQL
>   Server retrieves the execution plan from the cache and uses it (unless
>   there is a reason for recompilation). The potential problem arises
>   when the first time the stored procedure is executed, the set of
>   parameters generate an acceptable plan for that set of parameters but
>   very bad for other more common sets of parameters.

One of the solutions in the link provided is to use local variables. E.g what you are already doing.

Comment: Thanks for the update

Comment: @VenkateshKopulaSivakumar No problem sir, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answers your question (or what I understood about it):

[Global variables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143036/global-variables-in-sql)